# I would like to know if I can report a sexually explicit blog to HR anonymously

Tags: sexual-harassment

My question is: how can one report this anonymously? I was planning on sending an email with links and screenshots of everything in this blog, perhaps even calling an HR representative and telling him/her what the blog is.

Comment: "There is a fellow employee who works in the trading division and told me to check out his blog." - did he approach you, at work, invite you to visit his blog and give you details on how to find it, all at work?  Because, then, yes, I'd say that is definitely sexual harassment, for those who say otherwise.

Comment: Check your company HR site. It may even provide a service for anonymous reports about (sexual) harassment.

Comment: @L.Dutch Yes each company I've been at has a hotline you call to report anything of concern. You just leave a message.

Comment: @user477465 If the coworker shared it with you, perhaps he shared it with others. Try to find out if others viewed the blog and if so, reporting it cannot possibly be tied back to you unless you specify something uniquely told to you.

Comment: " there is also another employee who is being used in this blog as a target of his harassment."

This is the bit HR will be most interested in.  The blog itself is a lesser issue; if he's actually harassing someone at work and has been foolish enough to write a blog post confessing to it, then he'll more than likely be out the door.

Comment: "He states the company he works for and the location of the company" -
 pretty sure this would fall under 'Bringing the Company into Disrepute', in some jurisdictions (IANAL) the fact this was done in his own time may be irrelevant.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom Basically he posts pictures of two employees at the company and says all the sexually explicit things he wants to do to her. However, I don't know if he's ever even had in-person conversations with these women. I don't know what his relationship is with them, I only recognize them from the company. In the blog post he hasn't 'confessed' to sexually harassing them in person, he just harasses them online

Comment: There's scant detail, so one has to read the edit history to get a better understanding of the situation. That the blog appears to belongs to a coworker who posts images of female coworkers and proceeds to list the explicit sexual acts he would perform on them sounds illegal, and should first be reported to the police.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> how can one report this anonymously?

Send the relevant information on a document to HR via regular postal mail, **do not send the information via email**).  *Do not include a return address, and pay any mailing fees with cash.*  If you have to supply a return address, use the HQ address in the Netherlands for that.

This should get the job done and protect you from being the one who reported.  If you want to be extra cautious *wear gloves when dealing with the paper*.

It is the only way I can think of to report it without being potentially named as the accuser, especially if the place you work at has a bunch of security cameras.

Comment: @user477465, he asked you to check out his blog knowing it was like this. You are in fact being sexually harassed unless previous conversations with him led him to believe that you shared his offensive views of women. If looking at this made you uncomfortable, and I presume it does since you want to report it, then this was harassment to ask you to go read this offensive content.

Comment: Just say something like, take a look at employee BLAH BLAH's blog.  You may not want to be associated with this type of person...

Comment: @user477465 **DON'T** say on the letter that you work for the company this will basically make that, that person can track somehow to you. Just do as @IamSoNotListening `Look at the blog of this dude, bye.`

Comment: @user477465 recorded delivery and send it as "a concerned friend" and say that the owner of the blog has been harassing some of their employees.

or send it to all the board members via post I would also join the MHP union  

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_of_Managerial_and_Professional_Staff_Unions

Comment: This is drug dealer level opsec. Quite unnecessary when nothing illegal is involved. Use a throwaway email (no sign up), and if you're (overly) concerned that they'll go to the trouble of using the courts to get your IP from the throwaway service, go to an internet cafe and use it over a web-based proxy - or for a long-term option setup Tor over a VPN. Snail mail is an odd choice for this.

Comment: @user477465 not really I was suggesting that you sign it "a friend"  this was the common at one place I worked where the internal security team had a terrifying reputation and you might not want to draw there attention to you personaly